# how can i call the external custom .dll file written in c# from Delphi Script?

Tags: c#, delphi, inno-setup

```
using System;

namespace Example1
{
class Program
  {
   public static void portAvailable(IPAddress ipa,int port)
    {
try
{
      System.Net.Sockets.Socket sock = new    
      System.Net.Sockets.Socket(System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
      System.Net.Sockets.SocketType.Stream, System.Net.Sockets.ProtocolType.Tcp);
  sock.Connect(ipa, portno);
  if (sock.Connected == true)  // Port is in use and connection is successful
  MessageBox.Show("Port is Closed");
  sock.Close();

}
catch (System.Net.Sockets.SocketException ex)
{
if (ex.ErrorCode == 10061)  // Port is unused and could not establish connection 
     MessageBox.Show("Port is Open!");
else
     MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}

  }


 static void Main(string[] args)
  { 
            string hostName=Dns.GetHostname();
    int port=Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    IPAddress ipa = (IPAddress) Dns.GetHostAddresses(hostName)[0];
             portAvailable(ipa,port);


  }
 }
}
```

how can i call portAvailable() function from this .dll in Delphi for InnoSetup? what's wrong with code  posted above  ?i tried to access this .dll in my InnoSetup but when  user entering port  number it is not checking. i supposed  to install the setup in the available ports only.when the  user  enters  the  port which is in us  then it should  notify to  ask for other port number.please  solve this problem

```
  function portAvailable(
      ipa :IPAddress;
      port : int;):void;external 'Program.dll';
```

i am trying to call the function in Program.dll here.

Comment: That also doesn't much look like a DLL. Looks more like an executable. You've also not even shown how you are attempting to call this from Inno. Do you really want to fire up .net for such a trivial tasks as this? Seems like massive overkill.

Comment: If you're "coincidentally" looking for [How to check whether the entered port number is in use or not ?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21259517/960757), then I think you're doing it wrong with this code. You should attempt to bind a socket to an endpoint.

Answer (score 2):

.NET DLL are not native DLL so you can't call methods directly usually, you have to expose them somehow using either a mixed mode C++/CLI assembly or COM.

I'm not sure what COM interop Inno has (if any). You might find it easy to just build out an executable and call it from Inno with command line arguments.

**Addendum:**

There's also a third party package called [Unmanaged Exports](https://sites.google.com/site/robertgiesecke/Home/uploads/unmanagedexports) you can try which works similar to `DllImport`, although I've not tried this myself.

Comment: You can use [`Unmanaged Exports`](https://sites.google.com/site/robertgiesecke/Home/uploads/unmanagedexports) package.

Comment: @TLama Interesting never seen that before, I'll have to have a play with that.

Comment: UnmanagedExports is amazing, but it is also a work of black magic. Mixed mode C++/CLI at least lets you know what you are doing.